# Cannot get sysbench to stop at max time

Tags: bash, benchmark

I am looking to stress test a machine using `sysbench` so that I can get the CPU temperature to write to a file each second. Right now the test runs past the max time that I set. How to get it to stop after the time for the max time?

```
#!/bin/bash
end=$((SECONDS+30))

echo $(vcgencmd measure_temp | egrep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*') >> ~/research/temperatures.txt

sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=2000000 run --max-time=10

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
    echo $(vcgencmd measure_temp | egrep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*') >> ~/research/temperatures.txt

done
```

The test then runs for over 20 seconds and does not stop at 10 seconds:

```
$ ./stress-test
sysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 1

Doing CPU performance benchmark

Threads started!
Time limit exceeded, exiting...
Done.

Maximum prime number checked in CPU test: 2000000


Test execution summary:
    total time:                          24.7510s
    total number of events:              1
    total time taken by event execution: 24.7387
    per-request statistics:
         min:                              24738.74ms
         avg:                              24738.74ms
         max:                              24738.74ms
         approx.  95 percentile:         10000000.00ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           1.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   24.7387/0.00
```

I just have the time set low for now to ensure the test stops without waiting for the full time that I will be testing.